# Is it possible to deploy serverless framework with container images using GitHub actions

Tags: aws-lambda, github-actions, serverless-framework

Currently we have a lambda deployment that needs to be in a container due to the size of the python libraries used. It’s deployed from a developer’s machine using the Serverless framework CLI

Separately we deploy other lambdas via serverless using GitHub actions - so the code base is shared.

Is there any way (and I’ve looked but can’t find an answer!) that we can deploy a container image from GitHub?

Or are we better off putting the libraries in a layer container image (deployed as at present) and then moving the code itself to GitHub where it can be viewed centrally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Just build image with your code and dependencies, push to ECR and then deploy it as a containerized lambda.

```
name: Deploy to AWS Lambda

on:
 push:
   branches:
     - main

jobs:
 deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Login to AWS ECR
  uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

- name: Build Docker image
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: your-registry-url/your-image-name:latest

- name: Deploy to AWS Lambda
  uses: serverless/github-action@v1
  with:
    args: deploy
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```